# Files, modified in branch don't revert after switch

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, branch

I have a branch with some changes. When I switch back to trunk, I still see the changes of files I've modified in branch.

Can I change this behavior somehow, so any actions done in branch would not be visible in other branch or trunk after switch?

P.S.: using TortoiseSVN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a branch with some changes. When I switch back to trunk, I
>   still see the changes of files I've modified in branch.

This can only happen when you have local uncommitted changes in your working copy. If you made commits to the branch, did not merge them and you switch to trunk, you will not see the changes from the branch.